# Overflow in android system bar xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i'm having a problem with mi UI, when it renders, i'm having this as result:[image: overflow icon]

I want to know where to delete it from that menu, I'm using xamarin forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This menu shouldn't be displayed if your project is targeting Android version >=14 (4.0). Go to you project settings and change it to a newer version (my personal default choice is 4.0.3 (v15)).[image]

Comment: solved, i've done what you said and changed my project to target version v15